# Ember - object related item lost on page reload

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have Order and PaymentMethod models in Ember with a many-to-one relationship like so:

#### order.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    paymentStatus: DS.attr('number', { defaultValue: 1 }),
    paymentMethod: DS.belongsTo('payment-method'),
})
```

#### payment-method.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    orderPaymentMethods: DS.hasMany('order')
})
```

The order is saved to the database - all fine. I then have a route review-order, which obtains the order model (my API is only returning order models for the current logged in user)

#### review-order.js

```
export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        const order = this.store.findAll('order', { include: 'payment_method' }).then((orders) => {
           return orders.filterBy('paymentStatus', 1).get('lastObject');
       });
       return order;
   }
});
```

In my review-order template, I am printing out the payment method relationship like so

```
{{model.paymentMethod.name}}
```

This works fine I transition to the review-order route after the order is created - it prints the name of the payment method. However, if I refresh the review-order page, this is lost, and I have no idea why!

Comment: Are you using the ember-cli-mirage for your development env? if so then it is because of mirage, which gets refreshed on browse/page refresh.

Comment: @Bhabani Panigrahi - sorry I should have made clear, no using the Django Rest Framework

Comment: What does server return on GET /api/orders?
Is paymentMethod field filled?

Comment: @DmytroKalinin The model for review-order route can obtain the data from the user object after logging in, or I can make a call to api/order. Doing the latter then gives me multiple order items with null values for the ID. (I would appreciate any help understanding why this is happening!) So, I am using the user object method. I am including the user's orders, order items and order payment method. In my response the correct data is present in the included payload and for the data relationship. Not enough room here - can we start a chat?

Comment: In the end I am creating an extra field in my response from Django, a nested object for payment method (paymentMethodField) which I can reference directly in my template as model.paymentMethodField.name for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the full and detailed question! I am going to attempt an answer but I don't have 100% of the information that I would need to be sure this will answer the issue for your exact situation but hopefully it will still be useful and you can extract what you need from it.

The overall problem that you mentioned, that the data is not fully loaded correctly on a refresh, is likely caused by the API response not having all of the information that it needs. If you check the Web Dev Tools on chrome you will be able to verify that this is the case.

If you open dev tools, open the network tab and find the query that is loading your data then we can verify this. I don't know how familiar you are with dev tools but if you open them and refresh the page you will see all of the requests that the browser made. You can then filter by XHR to find the API query:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Network tab]

You will then be able to click on the request in question and use the **preview** tab to explore the data that is available:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Data Preview]

By looking at this data you will be able to verify if the required relationship is set up, and you will also be able to very if the correct data is also included in the `includes` section of the JSON:API response. For an example of what this should look like you can check out the [examples page for the official JSON:API documentation](https://jsonapi.org/examples/)

We spent a little bit of time trying to replicate your issue using [Mirage](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/) so that we could show the exact problem that you were having. It is a bit of a toy example but it does replicate the error and shows how the method I have described above fixes the issue.

Firstly I replicated your models exactly as you described them, then I created a Mirage endpoint to handle requests to get a single order:

```js
  this.get('/orders/:id', (schema, request) => {
    let responseData = {
      data: {
        id: request.params.id,
        type: 'orders',
        attributes: { 'payment-status': 1 },
        relationships: {
          "payment-method": {
            data: { id: "42", type: "payment-methods" }
          }
        }
      }
    };

    if(request.queryParams.include === "payment_method") {
      responseData.included = [{
        type: "payment-methods",
        id: "42",
        attributes: { name: "Credit Card" }
      }];
    }

    return responseData;
  });
```

You will see that if the `queryParams` includes `?include=payment_method` it makes sure that the payment method is included in the response JSON.

---

One other thing that I noticed about your example was that your `model()` hook in the `review-order.js` route seems a bit unconventional When I was going through this example I made use of a dynamic segment on the `review-order` route and made sure that I passed the order object when transitioning to it. Here is my Router definition:

```js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('review-order', { path: '/review/:id'});
});
```

I then created a simple button with a `createOrder()` action to simulate creating an order:

```js
  actions: {
    createOrder() {
      let paymentMethod = this.store.createRecord('payment-method', {
        name: 'Credit Card'
      });

      let order = this.store.createRecord('order', {
        id: 'not-null',
        paymentStatus: 1,
        paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
      });

      // we don't actually save because I don't have a backend setup correctly
      // order.save().then(() => { })

      // when we're done transition to review route with the model
      this.transitionToRoute('review-order', order);
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I am including the order object in the `transitionToRoute()` call.

Then we can simplify the `model()` hook in your route a little bit:

```js
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('order', params.id, { include: 'payment_method'})
  }
```

I hope that helps you figure out your issue

---

This question was answered as part of "May I Ask a Question" Season 2 Episode 4. If you would like to see us discuss this answer in full you can check out the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1udsGt8F9g

Comment: many thanks for getting back with this very comprehensive answer! If you want I can show you exactly what I'm doing, and the responses I'm getting back from my API. Please let me know if you want to start a chat on this

Comment: Yea sure, I'm on the Ember Community Discord if you want to chat more directly about this. Did you try any of the things that I suggested in the answer? did they help at all?

Comment: thanks for getting back. I am getting the correct response back on a page refresh - the desired relationships and included data looks correct to me - so I do need to investigate this more fully.